# Method post request not working but Get method is working in Laravel 5

Tags: post, laravel-5

i am getting blank page for post request, but code is working well for get method.

Here my code for Form:

```
<form class=`search_form` action=`index.php/packages` method=`post`>  
<div class=`search domain_search`>
<div class=`input_box`>
<input type=`text` id=`emailText` placeholder=`Your Business Name...` class=`user_name` onkeyup=`emailsearch()` name=`subDomainText`>
<input id=`token` name=`token` type=`hidden` value=`{{$encrypted_token}}`>
</div>
<div class=`input_button_box`>
<input class=`btn-seconsdary` type=`submit` value=`Submit`></div>
<div class=`clearfix`></div>
</div>
</form>
```

> Route:

```
Route::post(`domainsearch`, `siteController@domainsearch`);
```

> Controller:

```
public function domainsearch()
    {
        $data[`user`] = \Input::get(`subDomainText`); 
        return view(`email_search`,$data);
    }
```

Comment: watch out your action. and it is working with get method because input class is getting that feild from  url.

Comment: action should be only 'packages'..? instead of 'index.php/packages..'

Comment: give it to domainsearch ,as you described it in your routs.so on form submit it will check in route with name domainsearch and then it will linked to domainsearch action in your controller.just echo 'ok';exit;in top of your action to check it is reaching there or not.

Comment: it works or not? @Neelam